# JSF view displaying outdated value

Tags: jpa, view, jsf-1.2, java-ee-5

I have two entities and a backing bean in my application. Following, a simplified version of it:

**Controller and Models:**

```
class BackingBean {
    private List<A> collectionOfA;
    private A currentA;
    private B currentB;

    private String newDescription;

    // accessors

    public void prepareForUpdate(ActionEvent e) {
        currentA = (A) e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("a");
        currentB = (B) e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("b");
    }

    public void save(ActionEvent e) {
        // method to save b
        b.setName("changing the name");
        b.setSomeNumber(2);
        b.setDescription(newDescription);
        entityManager.merge(b);
    }
}

@Entity
class A {
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<B> bs;
}

@Entity
class B {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int someNumber;
}
```

**View:**

```
<div>
    <!-- some popup with inputs for updating B -->
    <h:inputText value="#{backingBean.currentB}" />
    <h:commandLink actionListener="#{backingBean.save}" />
</div>

<ui:repeat value="#{backingBean.collectionOfA}" var="a">
    <h:outputText>#{a.name}</h:outputText>

    <ui:repeat value="#{a.bs}" var="b">
        #{b.name}
        #{b.description}
        #{b.someNumber}
        <h:commandLink actionListener="#{backingBean.prepareForUpdate}">
            <f:attribute name="a" value="#{a}" />
            <f:attribute name="b" value="#{b}" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

Assuming that, when I click the `commandLink` for `prepareForUpdate()`, the popup shows, my problem is this: when I save the `currentB` entity, every field of the entity is updated in the view. However, an instant after, the field `b.description` is rendered again with the old value. When I check the database, the description is, in fact, updated, as it is if I refresh the page.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Try `<h:dataTable>` instead of `<ui:repeat>` and report back. The `<ui:repeat>` is known to have peculiar state saving problems in Mojarra.

Comment: Well, it turns out that I've got a stupid problem. `b.description` was being referred in another `inputText`, and that was the root cause.